# Jenkins Git branch is always shows HEAD detached at

Tags: git, jenkins

In Jenkins Source Code Management, I put `refs/heads/dev` into the Branches to build->Branch Specifier (blank for 'any').

And in the physical machine which Jenkins server depends on, when I type in `git branch`, I would expect it to should show `* dev` as current branch instead of `* (HEAD detached at 0952s96)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the expected result of `git checkout refs/heads/dev`. Try `dev` instead of `refs/heads/dev`. But in most cases, it doesn't matter if it's in detached HEAD state as long as `HEAD` and `refs/heads/dev` point to the same commit.

Comment: either put `refs/heads/dev` or `dev ` into Jenkins, the local is always shows `HEAD `, have no idea why, so, I use the parameter `$gitlabSourceBranch` from Jenkins env. This will give me the correct branch name instead of `Head`. However, this way is only work when Jenkins Job start automatically, and it does not work if it is started by manually.

Comment: @yeyimilk Try printing `$gitlabSourceBranch` in different cases. `dev` or `refs/heads/dev` may be resolved as a commit hash by Jenkins. `git checkout <commit-hash>` also results in detached HEAD.